# Show HTML code while page is loading

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to show a HTML code while the page content is loading. I tried a few ways but I was unable to get it to work.

I want to show this code while the page is loading:

```
<div class="spinner"></div>
    <div class="double-bounce1"></div>
    <div class="double-bounce2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what ways did you try? why didn't they work?

Comment: using jQuery on your page?

Comment: I want to show HTML code not an image. I tried this: http://bradsknutson.com/blog/display-loading-image-while-page-loads/ but I was unable to show HTML Code.

Comment: There is something in your HTML Code to show?

Comment: Yes. It is a loader. http://pastebin.com/cUbCg6JT

Comment: please try something before....create a fiddle or something...that way I think u'll get more help....by the way I checked out that blog and his demo....Its working fine....did u include jquery in your project....did you have enough content on your page.....because loader stops after the all the content loading have been finished....he uses callback to $(windows).load() function....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to position the preloader on the top of the content and there also was an error in html, here the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/20ovsb7n/

Here is used Jquery so you need to add that if not already included. I will show:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="path/to/your/jquery.js"><\/script>'); /script>
```

1) css to put preloader on the top of the content:

```
.preloader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: #FFF;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

2) add js to remove that preloader after the page is completly loaded (with images, etc)

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('.spinner').fadeOut(600);
});
```

NB: somtimes the loading event cant be fired due to loading problems and other things so we must set an max time loading, example with 4 sec time limit :

```
function preloaderhide() {
    $('.spinner').fadeOut(600);
}

$(window).load(function () {
   preloaderhide();
});

window.setTimeout(preloaderhide,4000);
```

And now lets hide the scrollbars until the page loading to prevent user scrolling:

http://jsfiddle.net/20ovsb7n/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').css("overflow","hidden");
});
```

change the preloaderhide()

```
function preloaderhide() {
    $('body').css("overflow","auto");
    $('.spinner').fadeOut(600);
}
```

**LATEST FIDDLE UPDATE**: http://jsfiddle.net/20ovsb7n/7/

Comment: The loader worked but it doesn't disappear after the page loads. It is live here: http://www.dip223.com/ Please take a look :)

Comment: Can you create some demo page that i can check? I posted the code but forgot to update the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/20ovsb7n/6/

Comment: Paste the code on the top of loader.js as it is in JsFiddle, check for HTMl thare is an error in your, check css.

Answer (score 0):

Do it dinamically. Is the best (And I think unique) way.

You page will load with that code and also a JavaScript code that will load the index using Ajax. After Ajax loads it will write the resusts in the document or do whatever you like.

You can start here: http://w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

You can have a second index2.html file that will be the main and index.html will load that file using Ajax. This is rudimentary but will work as intended. Less rudimentary will be to use a template system, like open source web software do (forums, and such things) but that's another question right now.

Some browsers does not render the web until all content is loaded, so using preloaders embeded in the site will not work as intended, on the other hand this code will work in any browser with JavaScript enabled.

By the way browsers that don't renders the website until all content is loaded are a very minimum part of percentage of browsers used currently.

Comment: Can you please tell me what code to use? I am very new to JQuery

Comment: Is a bit large to explain. You can start here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp You can have a second index2.html file that will be the main and index.html will load that file using Ajax. This is rudimentary but will work as intended. Some browsers does not render the web until all content is loaded, so using preloaders embeded in the site will not work as intended, on the other hand this code will work in any browser with JavaScript enabled. Btw browsers that don't renders the website until all content is loaded are a very minimum part of the current browsers.